# C# GeckoFX - Calling a JS function from the navigated Page

Tags: javascript, c#, geckofx

I am trying to call my function "initialize" in the navigated page using GeckFX(version 33),
I have tried the following actions:

```
_wb.Navigate("javascript:void(initialize());");
```

and

```
using (Gecko.AutoJSContext context = new AutoJSContext(_wb.Window.JSContext))
{
    var result = context.EvaluateScript("initialize();", _wb.Window.DomWindow);
}
```

both didn't work.
the first one didn't even return an error, the second one returned the following error message:

> Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.

I am performing those actions in the "DocumentCompleted" event handler.
Is there something I am missing?

my guess is that it didn't finish loading the page as when I stop in debug mode I don't see the web page from within this even handler(only when i continue it appears)

any ideas how to make it work?
thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the issue,
I should have used:

```
Application.DoEvents();
```

and then call

```
_wb.Navigate("javascript:void(initialize());");
```